# Equivalent notation for a strictly convex function is not strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

and, we define the following function: $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (n-1-0.1i)(x_i)^2$.

This function is a convex function since it can be written as $x^T Q x $ where

$Q = \begin{pmatrix} n -1-0.1i & 0 &  \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & n-1 - 0.1i & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots &  & n-1-0.1i \end{pmatrix} \\$

is a positive definite matrix.

I am trying to reformulate this function by using $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ only. Thus, I rewrite $x_i = x_i^+ - x_i ^  -$ where $x_i^+,x_i^-\in \mathbb{R}_+$

So I write $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (n-1-0.1i)(x_i^+ - x_i^-)^2$ and $Q$ becomes:

$Q^* = \begin{pmatrix} n-1-0.1 i & -(n-1-0.1i) & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
-(n-1 -0.1i) & n-1-0.1i & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 
0 & 0 & n-1-0.1i & -(n-1-0.1i) & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & -(n-1-0.1i) & n-1-0.1i & \ldots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{pmatrix}$

The new $Q^*$ is not positive definite, so $f(x)$ is not convex. How can I  get this equivalent notation as strictly convex?

Comment: It looks positive semidefinite to me.

Comment: In Matlab I am trying to get the Cholesky Decomp and it says:
Error using chol
Matrix must be positive definite.

Comment: Cholesky only works on positive definite matrices, you have a positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: Eventually, I want to use the Chol Decomp. Does this imply equivalent notations can lose positive definiteness?

Comment: $Q$ should not contain $i$ btw

Comment: I think $i$ is okay. Why not?

Comment: In the first row i is 1, in the second row its 2 etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new function is not strictly convex, since it is constant on the line $x_i^+ = x_i^-$. However, your function is still convex, as a convex function of an affine function is convex (easily proved with the definition of convexity).